# Remove or unset super attribute from cart in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have been trying to remove or unset  super attribute (configurable product) on cart page which have null value.

I have attached screen shot.

[image]

I have two option color and premium colors if i get color option value null than it will remove from cart programatically and also remove from sales order.

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
$_customOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
```

var dump the result and check `$_customOptions` or `$_customOptions['info_buyRequest']`. You will find useful information.